# SMSMessageTracking Data View - Differences Between Undelivered and Delivered Fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-views

We are trying to reterive data from the _SMSMessageTracking data view in order to populate another DE with undelivered and delivered statuses.

We've found there is a difference between Undelivered and Delivered fields - i.e. they are not always populated with the opposite values. In addition, there are records where Undelivered is null whereas Delivered = 1.

We did not find any explanation on the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) for the differences observed above. Could anyone clear this up why is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this data view.  It serves both MobileConnect and TXM SMS sends.  I'd suggest opening a support case and escalating until it gets acknowledged and addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just closed a support case regarding this view (#41900016).  Here's what I learned:

1. Delivery fields are updated as the send process is occurring.  If the delivery status changes the `Sent`, `Delivered`, `Undelivered`, and `IsValid` fields are updated on existing rows in this view.  Any time an existing field is updated then the `ModifiedDateTime` is also updated. I've tested this scenario with valid & invalid mobile numbers and some custom AMPscript send logging in the SMS message.
2. If there's a delivery issue, the code in `SMSStandardStatusCodeID` can be correlated with the error codes listed on the [SMS Status Codes wiki page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/sms-status-codes.html).  The value in the `Description` field is helpful in this case.
3. `MobileMessageTrackingID` is unique per Business Unit for each individual send.
4. If these messages are being sent via the [Transactional Message API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/transactional-messaging-api.html), you can also do a retrieve on the [delivery status endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getSMSSendStatusForRecipient.html) using the `messageKey` from the original send response.
5. There is also ongoing discussion to get `messageKey` added to this data view, so that TXM SMS sends can be correlated 1:1 for delivery status confirmation.
6. There are some updates coming to the [wiki page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) outlining the field lengths of the text fields.  While you wait, here they are (in bold):

| Field Name | Data Type | Length | Primary Key | Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MobileMessageTrackingID | Number |  | TRUE | TRUE |
| EID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| MID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| Mobile | Phone |  | FALSE | TRUE |
| MessageID | Number |  | FALSE | TRUE |
| KeywordID | Text | **16** | FALSE | FALSE |
| CodeID | Text | **16** | FALSE | FALSE |
| ConversationID | Text | **8** | FALSE | FALSE |
| CampaignID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| Sent | Boolean |  | FALSE | TRUE |
| Delivered | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| Undelivered | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| Unsub | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| OptIn | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| OptOut | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| Outbound | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| Inbound | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| CreateDateTime | Date |  | FALSE | TRUE |
| ModifiedDateTime | Date |  | FALSE | TRUE |
| ActionDateTime | Date |  | FALSE | TRUE |
| MessageText | Text | **160** | FALSE | FALSE |
| IsTest | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| MobileMessageRecurrenceID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| ResponseToMobileMessageTrackingID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| IsValid | Boolean |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| InvalidationCode | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SendID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SendSplitID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SendSegmentID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SendJobID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SendGroupID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SendPersonID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SubscriberID | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| SubscriberKey | Text | **254** | FALSE | FALSE |
| SMSStandardStatusCodeId | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| Description | Text | **512** | FALSE | FALSE |
| Name | Text | **256** | FALSE | FALSE |
| ShortCode | Text | **50** | FALSE | FALSE |
| SharedKeyword | Text | **50** | FALSE | FALSE |
| Ordinal | Number |  | FALSE | FALSE |
| FromName | Text | **20** | FALSE | FALSE |
| JBActivityID | Text | **16** | FALSE | FALSE |
| JBDefinitionID | Text | **16** | FALSE | FALSE |

7. There's currently no way to correlate a native SMS Send Log data extension row to _SMSMessageTracking.  You can use AMPscript in the SMS message to write to a custom SMS Send log, but it means that you'll need to generate your own `messageKey`.

Hope that helps.  I know how frustrating it is.

**EDIT**:

I also found [this KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000355536&type=1) helpful in deciphering what columns in this view relate to which method of sending SMS.  This data is sourced from multiple places.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks so much for the detailed response and research. Do you specifically know why the Undelivered field is left NULL while the Delivered field value is TRUE in some scenarios? Thanks again

Comment: I'm assuming that they just set the flags as the events occur.